# Customize zsh errors

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to create a message for terminal errors.

But my code does not work! :(

```
local return_code=""
local code="%?"

if [ "$code" = "130" ]; then 
  return_code="%F{red}TERMINATED BY USER ↵%f"
elif [ "$code" = "0" ]; then
 return_code=""
else
 return_code="%F{red}${code} ↵%f" # <= always return
fi
```

Or I used another method

```
local code=$? # always return zero

if [ $code -eq 130 ]; then 
...
```

Comment: I think you need `$?` not `%?` -- $code will contain the _string_ "%?" which is not equal to 130 or to 0.

Comment: You'll need to show how you integrate that code into your zsh setup

Comment: I also use $? but $? return 0 %? return right value but i don't know why not condition not work

Comment: Oh, when you do `local code=$?`, the current status is from `local return_code=""`. Make sure `local code=$?` is the **first** thing you do in order to capture the exit status of the _previous command_.

Comment: `%?` is a *prompt escape* for displaying the exit status, but you don't need a shell conditional; you can embed something like `%(130?.%F{red}TERMINATED%f.%(?..%F{red}%?%f))` in your prompt. (Yes, it looks like line noise.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the comments and thank you

```
local e001="%(1?.(!) GENERAL ERROR%f ↵."
local e002="%(2?.(!) MISUSE OF SHELL BUILTINS%f ↵."
local e126="%(126?.(!) COMMAND INVOKED CANNOT EXECUTE%f ↵."
local e127="%(127?.(!) COMMAND NOT FOUND%f ↵."
local e128="%(128?.(!) INVALID ARGUMENT TO EXIT%f ↵."
local e130="%(130?.(!) TERMINATED BY USER%f ↵."
local e255="%(255?.(!) EXIT STATUS OUT OF RANGE%f ↵."


local return_code="%F{red}${e001}${e002}${e126}${e127}${e128}${e130}${e255}%(?..%?%f ↵)"
```

There was no need for conditions